# Why this XML script show message only once?

Tags: javascript, vbscript, wsh

This code is from Microsoft script56.chm. Why does it show message only once?

I'm learning Windows Script Host and running `xml.wsf` in Windows command line.

```xml
<package>
    <job id="DoneInVBS">
    <?job debug="true"?>
        <script language="VBScript">
            WScript.Echo "This is VBScript"
        </script>
    </job>

    <job id="DoneInJS">
    <?job debug="true"?>
        <script language="JScript">
            WScript.Echo("This is JScript"); 
        </script>
    </job>
</package>
```

I expect it shows two messages.

Comment: How did you call it? - `cscript myScript.wsf //job:DoneInVBS //job:DoneInJS`

Comment: Thank you! I see. I run `cscript js.wsf` in cmd and it showed only `This is VBScript`.

Answer (score 0):

As [I mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57972243/why-this-xml-script-show-message-only-once/57986853#comment102354553_57972243), you need to specify both Jobs during execution or it will run the first one in the file, in this case `DoneInVBS`.

The documentation for Job element is very clear *(see script56.chm)*

> To run the second job in the Windows Script file, myScript.wsf, type the following at the command prompt.
>
> ```
> cscript myScript.wsf //job:DoneInJS
> ```
>
> To run both jobs in `myScript.wsf`, type the following at the command prompt.
>
> ```
> cscript myScript.wsf //job:DoneInVBS //job:DoneInJS
> ```